# Using the Windows.Media.Speechrecognition namespace in a Qt C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, windows-api-code-pack

I'm trying to develop a speech-to-text-input with the Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition namespace as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.aspx

Now, I'm working in Qt and apparently, there's no such thing as a Windows namespace:

```
using namespace Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

results in

> C2653: "Windows" no class or namespace

Okay, so I figured I might have to include something or add a library to my pro-file, but I can't find anything about what and where to get it.

In case the question comes up: I'm using this, because I need the speech input to accept languages other than English only.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include `Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.h` header. From desktop apps, the namespace is actually `ABI::Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition`. You'll also need to use WRL to call it. You can create the `SpeechRecognizer` object like this:

```
#include <roapi.h>
#include <Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.h>
#include <wrl.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Media::SpeechRecognition;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers;

int main()
{
    HRESULT hr = RoInitialize(RO_INIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    ComPtr<IInspectable> instance;
    ComPtr<ISpeechRecognizer> recognizer;
    hr = RoActivateInstance(HStringReference(L"Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition.SpeechRecognizer").Get(), &instance);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return hr;

    hr = instance.As(&recognizer);
    if (FAILED(hr))
         return hr;

    // do stuff with recognizer

    RoUninitialize();
}
```

You'll also need to link with `RuntimeObject.lib` for it to find functions like `RoInitialize` or `RoActivateInstance`.